# React, problem with mapping by the child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've got a problem with rendering components,
I have a component named 'Task' that is mapped by 'app' like:

```
{tasks.map((e, index) =>
    <Task key={e.id} title={e.title} description={e.description} id={e.id} status={e.status} remove={onRemoveTask}/>
    )}
```

with state of operations like (Task component):

```
const [operations, setOperations] = useState([])
    useEffect(() => {
        async function apiCall() {
            try {
                const data = await getOperations(id);
                setOperations(data)
            } catch(err) {
                console.log(err)
            }
        }
        apiCall();
    }, [])
```

After *console.log(operations)* there is a list of operations for each task.
The problem is, why I cannot map this array like:

```
{operations.map((e, index) => {
    <Operation key={e.id} operation={e}/>
})}
```

It renders nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array returned by the `.map()` method contains the values returned by the calls to the callback function.

Callback function of `.map()` method in the first code example, when called, returns the `Task` component. So the array returned by the `tasks.map(...)` contains the `Tasks` components and that is what gets rendered.

Callback function of `.map()` method in the last code example doesn't returns anything and that is why nothing gets rendered.

To make it work, you need to either omit the curly brackets

```
{operations.map((e, index) => (
    <Operation key={e.id} operation={e}/>
))}
```

or use the `return` keyword

```
{operations.map((e, index) => {
    return <Operation key={e.id} operation={e}/>
})}
```

When you use curly brackets with arrow function, you need to explicitly return something using the `return` keyword.

`.map()` in first code example works because if there are no curly brackets in arrow function, expression after the arrow `=>` is implicitly returned.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `return` statement for `map` callback:

```
operations.map(e => {
    return <Operation key={e.id} operation={e}/>
})

// same
operations.map(e => <Operation key={e.id} operation={e}/>)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify `return` in your map.
your code would be something like this:

```
{operations.map((e, index) => {
 return (
    <Operation key={e.id} operation={e}/>
 )
    
})}
```